# how to set default verbosity in ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible

I want to set default verbosity level in ansible. I set `default_verbosity=1` in `anisble.cfg` but this is not working. If I set environment variable `ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY=1` then I can see verbose level 1 output for my running tasks.

As per my current requirement, I want to set this value in ansible.cfg.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `verbosity` instead of `default_verbosity` in `ansible.cfg` file as:

```
$ cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
verbosity = 1
```

`verbosity` can be `0|1|2|3|4` representing `None|-v|-vv|-vvv|-vvvv`.

Assuming, the config file is kept under [specific locations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file) ansible looks into.

`ansible-config list` can also be used to list all the available configuration file settings.